# EXT JS Grid SelModel checkbox issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

How to set the Grid Selmodel Chekbox gets selected based on the Text field Value.
For Example:I have a grid of values like one,two,three and while page loading user will provide the value as Two in the textfield then the grid automatically gets selected the CheckBox of Two value.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Can you create one fiddle. It will help us understand easily

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have a store containing the values from the grid so you could search for the record containing your value from the text field and after that, use the grid's selection model to select it: grid.getSelectionModel().select(record).

I created a fiddle to demonstrate what I just said: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1gvv

I hope this helps